# IIS gets the value of the user differently on different machines

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have an application that is hosted in IIS.

When it is hosted on Machine One, the user name comes through as `mynetbios\username`.
When it is hosted on Machine Two, the user name comes through as `username@mydomain.net`.

The same code is running on both machines.  Both are running IIS 10.0.  Both have authentication set to enable Windows Authentication and disable all the others (including anonymous).

**Is there something in IIS that could control how the username comes through?**

Answer (score 0):

Domain\User is the "old" logon format, called down-level logon name. Also known by the names SAMAccountName and pre-Windows 2000 logon name.

User@Domain.com is a UPN - User Principal Name. It's the "preferred", newer logon format. It's an Internet-style login name, that should map to the user email name.

There's not really much of a difference. For more information about "User Name Formats", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats).